# What does -l $_ do in Perl, and how does it work?

Tags: perl

What is the meaning of the nest code

```
foreach (@items)
{
    if (-l $_)    ## this is what I don't understand: the meaning of -l
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: standart feature: I use `mkdir $directory unless (-e $directory);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at each thing:

```
foreach (@items) {
    ...
}
```

This `for` loop (`foreach` and `for` are the same command in Perl) is taking each item from the `@items` list, and setting it to `$_`. The `$_` is a special variable in Perl that is used as sort of a default variable. The idea is that you could do things like this:

```
foreach (@items) {
    s/foo/bar/;
    uc;
    print;
}
```

And each of those command would operate on that `$_` variable! If you simply say `print` with nothing else, it would print whatever is in `$_`. If you say `uc` and didn't mention a variable, it would uppercase whatever is in `$_`.

This is now discouraged for several reasons. First, `$_` is *global*, so there might be side effects that are not intended. For example, imagine you call a subroutine that mucked with the value of `$_`. You would suddenly be surprised that your program doesn't work.

The other `-l` is a [test](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) operator. This operator checks whether the file given is a symbolic link or not. I've linked to the Perldoc that explains all of the test operators.

If you're not knowledgeable in Unix or BASH/Korn/Bourne shell scripting, having a command that starts with a dash just looks weird. However, much of Perl's syntax was stolen... I mean *borrowed* from Unix shell and awk commands. In Unix, there's a command called [test](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) which you can use like this:

```
if test -L $FILE
then
    ....
fi
```

In Unix, that `-L` is a *parameter* to the *test* command, and in Unix, most parameters to commands start with dashes. Perl simply *borrowed* the same syntax dash and all.

Interestingly, if you read the Perldoc for these test commands, you will notice that like the `foreach` loop, the various test commands will use the `$_` variable if you don't give it a variable or file name. Whoever wrote that script could have written their loop like this:

```
foreach (@items)
{
    if (-l)   ## Notice no mention of the `$_` variable
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Yeah, that's soooo much clear!

Just for your information, The *modern* way as recommended by many Perl experts (*cough* [Damian Conway](http://www.manning.com/conway/) *cough*) is to avoid the `$_` variable whenever possible since it doesn't really add clarity and can cause problems. He also recommends just saying `for` and forgetting `foreach`, and using curly braces on the same line:

```
for my $file (@items) {
    if ( -l $file ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That might not help with the `-l` command, but at least you can see you're dealing with files, so you might suspect that `-l` has something to do with files.

Unfortunately, the Perldoc puts all of these file tests under the `-X` section and alphabetized under *X*, so if you're searching the Perldoc for a `-l` command, or any command that starts with a dash, you won't find it unless you know. However, at least you know now for the future where to look when you see something like this: `-s $file`.

Comment: `perldoc -f "-X"` works just fine, though. So does navigating to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html and searching for `-l`. When you say `"This is now discouraged for several reasons."`, you actually only mention one reason, and one that is not entirely true. `$_` is aliased to that particular loop. So unless you are using subroutines which (accidentally?) for some reason make use of global variables (bad practice), you're fine to use `$_` as much as you please. The reason I would choose is that it more explicitly states what's going on.

Comment: You said `$_` is special, but the only thing special about it is that it always refers to `$main::_`, something that's not relevant to the OP.

Comment: @ikegami `$_` special because it is the default variable that is used by some commands and that's relevant to the OP. Because it is a default variable, there can be side effects in its use.

Comment: Like you said, what's special is that some functions read it. The side effects happen no matter what var is used.

Comment: @TLP Yes, if you know to look for `-X` in Perldoc, you will find it. And, if you use the web brower's built in find text you will find it. And, you will even find it if you do the command line Perldoc command `perldoc -f -l`. However, you won't find it by looking at the function index, and you won't find it if you try to Google _perl function -1_ which is what many people attempt to do.

Comment: @ikegami Here's a side effect: I have a loop `for @list {`. In my loop I call a subroutine `foo($value);`. The subroutine uses the `$_` variable as a default for various functions. Later on in my program, I noticed that `@list` has been changed, but I can't figure out where it got changed.

Comment: Same side effect happens for `for my $x (@list)`

Answer (score 6):

It's an [operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) that checks if a file is a symbolic link.

Comment: Is there another way to check?

Comment: Purely for curiosity. I maintain some Perl scripts, and am looking for the most "wordy" way to test for something, including opening files, and so on, despite there being shortcuts.

Comment: Almost all of the -X ops use information from [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html), and `-l` is no exception. Or if you want silly, you could use Inline::Java to call a Java function to do the same.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Are you trying to obfuscate a script, or is this just an attempt at writing more "readable" code?

Comment: @TLP curiousity + maintenance = obfuscation and optimization

Comment: There are ways to open a file using some of the shortcut methods. I don't use Perl much, and can't remember them right now. I prefer to write it out longhand. I was just wondering if there were another way to write `if (-l $_)`. My question was not a comment on anyone's coding style, answers, or anything else. It was just pure curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

The [`-l` filetest operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) checks whether a file is a symbolic link.

The way `-l` works under the hood resembles the code below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl ':mode';

sub is_symlink {
  my($path) = @_;

  my $mode = (lstat $path)[2];
  die "$0: lstat $path: $!" unless defined $mode;

  return S_ISLNK $mode;
}

my @items = @ARGV;
foreach (@items) {
  if (is_symlink $_) {
    print "$0: link: $_\n";
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ln -s foo/bar/baz quux
$ ./flag-links flag-links quux
./flag-links: link: quux
```

Note the call to `lstat` and not `stat` because the latter would attempt to follow symlinks but never identify them!

To understand how Unix mode bits work, see the [accepted answer to “understanding and decoding the file mode value from stat function output.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15059931/123109)

Answer (score 4):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) :

```
 -l File is a symbolic link.
```