# Windows vs Linux file modes

Tags: python, file, filesystems, python-os

On a windows machine, I am trying to get a file's mode using the os module in python, like this (short snippet):

```
import os
from stat import *

file_stat = os.stat(path)
mode = file_stat[ST_MODE]
```

An example for the mode I got for a file is 33206.

My question is, how can I convert it to the linux-file mode method? (for example, 666).

Thanks to all repliers!

**Edit:**

found my answer down here :) for all who want to understand this topic further:

[understanding and decoding the file mode value from stat function output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055634/understanding-and-decoding-the-file-mode-value-from-stat-function-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this translates properly:

```
import os
import stat

file_stat = os.stat(path)
mode = file_stat[ST_MODE]
print oct(stat.S_IMODE(mode))
```

For your example:

```
>>>print oct(stat.S_IMODE(33206))
0666
```

[Took it from here. Read for more explanation](https://stomp.colorado.edu/blog/blog/2010/10/22/on-python-stat-octal-and-file-system-permissions/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Great help :)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to use:`os.system(r'attrib –h –s d:\your_file.txt')`       where you can use the attribute switches :
R – This command will assign the “Read-Only” attribute to your selected files or folders.
H – This command will assign the “Hidden” attribute to your selected files or folders.
A – This command will prepare your selected files or folders for “Archiving.”
S – This command will change your selected files or folders by assigning the “System” attribute.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem