# What is the meaning of each number of an inode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If I have the inode number: 263167, what is the meaning of 2, then of 6, then 3, and so on until 7...?

I did a research, but I didn't found something like this.

I want to know what is the purpose of every number of an inode. Maybe it is strange because I didn't saw this explanation before, but I know that every number has a special meaning.

Thank you all!

Comment: Inode numbers are arbitrary numbers assigned by the filesystem; the individual digits by themselves don't mean anything. Are you thinking of [file modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055634/understanding-and-decoding-the-file-mode-value-from-stat-function-output) instead?

Comment: @Thomas hmm, I can't understand file modes right now, if you use ```ls -i``` command in Linux, the first column represents the inode number of a file... I know what are hard and soft links, the concept of an inode as you access a file, but instead that file called the inode to access it... as you search for a domain address and DNS will translate it to you as an IP...

Comment: For now, I don't know if there is a relation between file mode and inodes... From history, inode was i-node, "i" stands from "index"... I know that an inode is a metadata (a data which represents other data) but what is the meaning of each number from an inode... There are 6 to 8 numbers, it depends on your OS... but what are the meaning of each number, that is my biggest unknown... Thank you!

Comment: There is no relation. I just thought you might be confusing the two, because in octal notation, each individual digit of the file mode _does_ have a meaning. But to use the DNS analogy, ask yourself the question: what is the meaning of the 2 in "151.101.129.69"? Answer: it doesn't have any. Same with inodes.

Comment: @Thomas So, an inode number is a random number?

Comment: @Thomas Wow... Big thanks! Be blessed!

Comment: Not random, but arbitrary. Determined by the file system, but there might be a pattern to it.

Comment: @Thomas Hi, sorry for my late, I want to close this question, could you answer this? I want to reward your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inode numbers are arbitrary numbers assigned by the filesystem; the individual digits by themselves don't mean anything. You are probably thinking of [file modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055634/understanding-and-decoding-the-file-mode-value-from-stat-function-output) instead.